# Generating random number for a Receipt

Tags: c++

What I want to do is create a simple receipt, which can be created by the user and then displayed, searched by the receipt number, and deleted by receipt number.

So far I have created a random number which is a set of four numbers. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to assign it to a new receipt.

This is the code, no errors are being displayed.

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <ctime>

        using namespace std;


        class cReceipt{
            private:
                cReceipt *nNext; 
                int nNumber, articleNum;
            public:
                char articleName[40];
                int price, ammound;
                    
            cReceipt(){cout<<"Alocating"<<endl;nNext=NULL;}
            ~cReceipt(){cout<<"Dealocating: "<< articleNum << " " << articleName << " " 
                    << price << " " << ammound <<endl;}
            
            public:
                void dealokate()
                {
                    cReceipt *previus,*rightNow;
                    previus=this;
                    rightNow=this->nNext;
                    
                    cout <<"Dealocation:" << endl; 
                    if (!rightNow)
                    {
                        cout <<"Nothing to dealocate" << endl; 
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    while(rightNow)
                    {
                    if (previus!=this)
                        delete previus;
                    previus=rightNow;
                    rightNow=rightNow->nNext;
                    }
                    
                    delete previus; 
                    this->nNext=NULL;
                }
                
                void articleGenerator()
                {
                    for (nNumber = 1; nNumber <= 4; nNumber++) 
                    {
                        articleNum = 0 + rand() % 9;
                        cout << articleNum;
                    }
                    cout << "\n";   
                }
                
                void input()
                {
                    cReceipt *zadnji, *novi; 
                    
                    zadnji=this;
                    while(zadnji->nNext)
                    zadnji=zadnji->nNext;
                    
                    novi = new cReceipt;
                    zadnji->nNext=novi;
                    
                    cout << "Items of Receipt: " << endl;
                    cout << "Recept number: " << novi->articleNum << endl;
                    cout << "Article name: "; cin >> novi->articleName;
                    cout << "Price:"; cin >> novi->price;
                    cout << "Ammound:"; cin >> novi->ammound;
                }
                
                void output()
                {
                    cReceipt *rightNow=this->nNext;
                        
                    while (rightNow)
                    {
                        cout << "Recept: " << rightNow->articleNum << endl;
                        cout << "Article name: " << rightNow->articleName << endl;
                        cout << "Price: " << rightNow->price << endl;
                        cout << "Ammound: " << rightNow->ammound << endl;
                        cout << "---" << endl;
                        rightNow=rightNow->nNext;
                    }
                }
        };

        int main()
        {
            setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
            
            srand(time(0));
            
            cReceipt cPointer;
                
            int chojc;
            
            cout << "Method(articleGenerator) on object(cPointer): ";
            cPointer.articleGenerator();
            
            do
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "=========================" << endl;
                cout << "0. Dealokation" << endl;
                cout << "1. Input." << endl;
                cout << "2. Output." << endl;
                cout << "Your choice: "; cin >> chojc;
                cout << "=========================" << endl;
                
                switch(chojc)
                {
                    case 0: 
                        cPointer.dealokate();
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        cPointer.input();
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        cPointer.output();
                        break;
                    case 90: 
                        break;  
                }
            }while(chojc!=90);
            
            system("PAUSE");
            return 0;   
        }
```

EDIT:
I changed the method to be a type of void to fix the return warning and called it to an object and uploaded the new code.

Here is a visual illustration of what I am trying to achieve
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZLT.png
So I want to connect a random number for each new Receipt.

Comment: Function's never called. UB, but since the code never get there unlikely to be the asker's problem. Unless the function not being called is part of the problem.

Comment: I have refined my question and solved the warning, but still can't generate random number.Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You're not freeing memory with `delete`. That will result in a memory leak.

Comment: Eny idea how to free up memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `cReceipt` is intended to represent a single receipt. So you need code outside of that class to generate your four receipts. Possibly stored in an array or std::vector. You would either need to use the cReceipt constructor. Or an accessor function (a function that provides public write or read access to a private member function) to the fields of cReceipt. For example: `articleNum`
will need either to be initialized in the constructor or have an accessor function providing write access.

Also, you will probably want more than one class `cReceipt` and another class that is a collection of receipts (in this case with 4 receipts). You may want to call it `cReceiptContainer`.

I'll let you work out the details as part of the learning process. Descriptions of both constructors and accessor functions are available in both textbooks and online.

Comment: Thank your wery much,